# Substring reurns a number value instead of varchar

Tags: mysql

```
$query = mysql_query(SELECT * FROM test WHERE SUBSTRING(date,0,4)="1392") //for example 1392
echo query['name'];
```

i want to get 4 first character and check its equal with 1392 or not .
 but its return 1054 my column name type  is varchar and i have no idea about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL count char from 1, not from 0 as php.
try

```
SUBSTRING(date,1,4)="1392"
```

or if you want the year

```
YEAR(date)="1392"
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring

**EDIT** test exemple

```
CREATE TABLE babak (name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, date VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO babak SELECT 'test', '1391/11/11';
INSERT INTO babak SELECT 'correct', '1932/11/11';

SELECT * FROM babak WHERE YEAR(date) = 1932;
+---------+------------+
| name    | date       |
+---------+------------+
| correct | 1932/11/11 |
+---------+------------+

SELECT * FROM babak WHERE SUBSTRING(date, 1, 4) = 1932;
+---------+------------+
| name    | date       |
+---------+------------+
| correct | 1932/11/11 |
+---------+------------+
```

Comment: again same problem its return a number

Comment: what is in date? if you want to fetch the year just use YEAR(date)

Comment: date is persian type like 1391/11/11 for examle i wanna get 4frist character and if equal then i echo uname

Comment: tanx my friend its ok ; i find out

Answer (score 1):

So your date is in `varchar` with the format `yyyy/MM/dd`, try this one:

```
SELECT   *
  FROM   test 
 WHERE   SUBSTRING(`date`,1,4) = '1932'
```

**[CLICK HERE FOR DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88ce9/7)**

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query only returns a resource, you need to use that resource to fetch the result

```
$resource = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM test WHERE SUBSTRING(date,1,4)="1392"')
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource);
echo $result['name'];
```

Comment: i know this my frind it was for test thank you for ur help my problem solved tanx alot

Comment: just added it incase someone find this question by googleing, then they have that answer to